# The best way to enumerate through a string in Rust? (chars() vs as_bytes())

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and I'm learning it using Rust Book.

Recently, I found this function there:

```rust
// Returns the number of characters in the first
// word of the given string

fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}
```

As you see, the authors were using String::as_bytes() method here to enumerate through a string. Then, they were casting the char ' ' to u8 type to check whether we've reached the end of the first word.

As I know, ther is another option, which looks much better:

```rust
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    for (i, item) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        if item == ' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }
    s.len()
}
```

Here, I'm using String::chars() method, and the function looks much cleaner.

So the question is: **is there any difference between these two things?** If so, which one is better and why?

Comment: Consider what would happen if the string is not ASCII, eg contains multibyte characters where `0x20` can have some significance other than space.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [`str::split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace).

Comment: @eggyal FYI that would not be UTF-8, so would be an invalid `String`/`str`. Every multi-byte codepoint has only bytes with values >= 0x80

Comment: @PitaJ:  fair point.  Is it just good discipline to treat ASCII characters distinctly from their bytes then, or is there some other difference to consider?

Comment: If searching for an ascii character, `bytes` is probably faster. But there are even faster ways like [`memchr`](https://docs.rs/memchr/latest/memchr/)

Comment: Note that the book used `bytes` because it later modifies the function to slice the string, and string slicing uses byte indexes.

Comment: @eggyal Even if it does not contain another `0x20`, it will still use wrong indices. Using `chars().enumerate()` is almost always wrong, you need `char_indices()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your string happens to be purely ASCII (where there is only one byte per character), the two functions should behave identically.

However, Rust was designed to support UTF8 strings, where a single character could be composed of multiple bytes, therefore using `s.chars()` should be preferred, it will allow your function to still work as expected if you have non-ascii characters in your string.

As @eggyal points out, Rust has a [str::split_whitespace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) method which returns an iterator over words, and this method will split all whitespace (instead of just spaces). You could use it like so:

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    if let Some(word) = s.split_whitespace().next() {
        word.len()
    }
    else {
       s.len() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: `s.bytes()` is likely more performant, since it only needs to increment by 1, whereas `s.chars()` needs to consider the current byte to determine how many bytes away is the next character. However, the performance difference is likely small and not worth the brittleness of `s.bytes`, especially if you're processing strings in a language other than English (since ascii was designed for English). To know for sure you should profile your code to see if the performance difference is even noticeable.